# Bulk delete "Build Failure" items from Backlog

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

While we weren't watching, our TFS build server generated almost 200 "Build Failure in Build" items in our product backlog. Is there a simple way to bulk remove them?

Comment: Any particular reason for the down vote? This is a legitimate question and I got a great answer. It's helpful to provide a reason if you think there is an issue with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to destroy these build failure bugs permanently or you just want to remove them from Backlog?

If you want to destroy them permanently (remove work items from the Team Foundation database), you can use the following code:

```
var tfctc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
var wis = tfctc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
var wiToDelete = new List<int>();
var wiql = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'teamprojectName' and [Title] Contains 'Build Failure in Build: ' and [State] = 'New' ";
var wic = wis.Query(wiql);
foreach (WorkItem wi in wic)
{
    wiToDelete.Add(wi.Id);
}
wis.DestroyWorkItems(wiToDelete);
```